# What's the name of a concept where objects take on forms out of different things?

Tags: technique-identification

I think the title is the most proper question that could come up in my mind, as for an example - take a look at 2014 ESC postcards:

[image: Danish flag]
[image: Swedish flag]

or this:

[image: Tennis racket]
[image: Tennis racket represented by a pool and a rubber duck]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These use the shape, color, and arrangement of familiar objects to simulate the appearance of something unrelated.  Would you consider this kind of "food art" in the same category: https://allthatsinteresting.com/food-art?

Comment: @fixer1234, I would probably say so, yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Optical illusion

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_illusion), this is

> an illusion caused by the visual system and characterized by a visual percept that arguably appears to differ from reality.

In the first two photographs (making it '(optical) illusion photography'), this 'visual percept' is a flag. Here the 'illusion' is caused by the (careful) positioning of objects in alignment relative to the point of view.

Another term often used is for this is '[forced perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forced_perspective)', which is a type of optical illusion.

Though the illusion is not as monumental as the word suggests, it functions basically the same as works like this one, the *Triumph of the Name of Jesus* by Giovanni Battista Gaulli:

[image: Triumph of the Name of Jesus by Giovanni Battista Gaulli - from Wikipedia]

This example is another sub-category of those optical illusions, referred to as *[trompe l'œil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trompe-l%27%C5%93il)* (from French, meaning 'fooling the eye'), a term which is almost exclusively to paintings. It is often used in conjunction with architectural forced perspective.

**Our perception tricks us into seeing more than the sum of the parts (like depth, light, &c.).**
The construction of (linear) perspective is also based on this principle.

Comment: I can't really figure out what the second set of photographs is about. If it is another optical illusion, I don't see it - if not, I think it should be posted as a separate question.